# How to get user selected option from dropdown in a table row with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of a dropdown in a table row that has been dynamically created from the server from data pulled from the database.
Example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select onChange="setPaymentAmt()">
        <option value="1">Option1</option>
        <option value="2">option2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <select onChange="setPaymentAmt()">
      <option  value="3">Option1</option>
      <option  value="4">option2</option>
    </select>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

If I want to grab the value from a user selected option for a specific row using jquery how do I get it?

Here is what I have tried:

```
function setPaymentAmt() {  
    var data = $(this).closest('select option:selected').val();
    alert(data);
}
```

when I alert that it shows undefined

Comment: What is calling `setPaymentAmt` ? Also you should read what `closest` do.

Comment: I have an onchange() event attached to the dropdown so that when a user clicks the dropdown and makes a selection it runs the setPaymentAmt() function.

Comment: If [zgood' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20981255/2324107) doesn't work, we'll need more information.

Comment: @user3170504 I have updated my answer with the new information you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to attach a change event to all your `<select>`'s, like so:

```
$('select').bind('change', function(){
    var data = $(this).val();
    alert(data);
});
```

OR if its dynamic:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
      var data = $(this).val();
      alert(data);
});
```

If you already have a change event attached to you `<select>`'s and you are calling `setPaymentAmt()` from that event then you will need to pass `setPaymentAmt()` a reference of the `<select>` that triggered the event. Like so:

```
//Inside your onchange event
var sel = $(this);
setPaymentAmt(sel);

function setPaymentAmt(sel) {  
    var data = sel.val();
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. In the html I included a reference to the <select> like you said: onchange="setPaymentOption($(this))" and then the function above. It works perfectly - thanks!